# How to assign a specific type to a discriminated union type in F#

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Suppose I have the following types:

```
type TypeA = { A: string }
type TypeB = { B: string }
```

and I have a union type for them both:

```
type MyUnionType = TypeA | TypeB
```

With a type just to contain the union type:

```
type MyContainer = { Union: MyUnionType }
```

now if I create an instance of one of the types in the union type:

```
let resultA = { A = "abc" }
```

when I try to assign that instance to the value in the container

```
let result = { Union = resultA }
```

the compiler complains, saying

> Compilation error (line 10, col 24): This expression was expected to have type MyUnionType but here has type TypeA

but `TypeA` ***is*** one of the valid types specified in the union! How can I assign it to my Union property?

Here is an example of the program: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fgJKpM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `type MyUnionType = TypeA | TypeB`, `TypeA` and `TypeB` do not refer to the previous `TypeA` and `TypeB` records, but are nullary constructors for the `MyUnionType` type. If you want them to contain values of those types you need to include them in the definition e.g.

```
type MyUnionType = TypeA of TypeA | TypeB of TypeB
```

You might want to rename the constructors to avoid confusion between them and the contained types.

you then need to supply the corresponding instance to the constructor:

```
let resultA = TypeA { A = "abc" }
```

Comment: I believe that the following form is also allowed: `let resultA = { TypeA.A = "abc"}`